# Can't call a method in the same class while overriding == operator c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, overriding, getter

I am trying to override the == operator in my project for a String_Data class. String_Data has a method getString() that returns the string held in the String_Data object. I am trying to call this method in my == override to compare the strings held by two String_Data objects. When I do this however I am being told that the String_Data object I'm using as an argument has no such method. I'm not sure what is going wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> 
#include "String_Data.h"

using namespace std;

std::string myString;
int stringCount;

String_Data::String_Data(std::string URL, int useCount)
{
    stringCount = useCount;
    myString = URL;
}

String_Data::~String_Data(void)
{
}

bool operator == (String_Data sd, String_Data sd2) {
return (sd.getString() == sd2.getString());
}

std::string getString() {
    return myString;
}
void increment() {
    stringCount++;
}

bool compare() {

}

int getCount() {
    return stringCount;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to call anything in the op== override. Include that, and your compiler errors

Comment: It seems you want to _overload_ rather than _override_ the equality operator: similar name, somewhat related, but quite different. The code you posted doesn't show the class declaration and the `getString()` function posted isn't a member.

Comment: @DietmarKühl it might be if this is the middle of a class declaration with the methods inline

Comment: @KateGregory: no, not really: you can't overload `operator==()` with two parameters as a member function. ... and you can't qualify members with the class name (although some compilers do allow the qualifications sometimes).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh, I know that, I'm just saying you can't be sure getString isn't a member.

Comment: I can post the whole code I just figured I would omit the code that wasn't pertinent but I'm still a student so I could be wrong I'll put the rest up.@KateGregory Also I know I am supposed to override the operator so I may be going at this completely wrong I'm sorry.

Comment: @user2084037: the point **isn't** to post _all_ code. The point is to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: @DietmarKühl that's what I was trying to do but your first comment kinda confused me so I figured better safe then sorry. Plus its really straight forward if it was a huge long thing I wouldn't have.

Comment: I'm just trying to get some help at this point this assignment is done  I'm just trying to learn for future refrence

Comment: What's the actual compiler error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info provided above I'm going to guess that you did not properly provide a `getString` method in your `String_Data` definition. When you try to invoke it from `operator ==` naturally the compiler will complain about that method not existing!

The simple fix is to make sure you provide the method in your `class String_Data`. Also, it seems like you meant to have `myString` and `stringCount` as actually members of `String_Data` rather than standalone global variables. Your class definition should look something more along the lines of:

```
// String_Data.h
class String_Data
{
  std::string myString;
  int stringCount;
public:
  //...
  std::string getString();
};
```

And your `getString` free function needs to be converted into a `String_Data` method:

```
std::string String_Data::getString()
{
  return myString;
}
```

That should correct the error you're getting from the overloaded `operator ==`. Note that `operator ==` should take its arguments by const ref since nothing is being modified:

```
bool operator == (const String_Data &sd, const String_Data &sd2);
```